# why possibility_1=0 and possibility_2=0 doesnt changing?

Tags: python

```
import math
import random


possibility_1=0
possibility_2=0

while True:
    list = [0, 1]
    number_1=random.choice(list)
    number_2=random.choice(list)
    number_3=random.choice(list)
    
    number_total=str(number_1)+","+str(number_2)+","+str(number_3)
    
    if number_total==(1,1,0) or number_total==(0,0,1):
        possibility_1 +=1

    if number_total==(1,1,1) or number_total==(0,0,0):
        possibility_2 +=1   

    print(str(number_total)+"      possibility_11= "+ str(possibility_1)+" possibility_12= "+ str(possibility_2))
```

guys the possibility_1 and possibility_2 doesn!t changing. Please help me I want to make a heads or tails code and simulate it then check the possibilities.

Comment: `number_total` is a sting that you're comparing with tuples

Comment: Why should they change? Talk me through it, step by step. I see that `number_total` is created by doing `str(number_1)+","+str(number_2)+","+str(number_3)`, and then an attempt is made to compare that result to (for example) `(1,1,0)`. Why should those two things ever be equal?

Comment: also, declare your list variable outside the while loop, just under the possibility variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like number_total is a string so the output would be "1,1,0" you are comparing with a tuple. This means the if statements will not be invoked.

`if number_total=="1,1,0" or number_total=="0,0,1":`